# Consuming REST-Webservices in Android

Tags: java, android, rest, parameters, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to consume some RESTful webservices in Android. I used Jersey to provide the webservices, and i'm using HttpURLConnection for the Android-client, my problem is: the parameters are not getting transfered to the server.

Here's my server-side code:

```
@Path("/user")
@RequestScoped
public class UserService implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public UserService() {

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Integer registerUser(@QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password, 
        @QueryParam("registrationToken") String registrationToken) {
        User user = new User(username, password, registrationToken);
        em.persist(user);
        System.out.println("registerUser erfolgreich aufgerufen. Userid: " + user.getId());
        return user.getId();
    }

}
```

For the Android client i created the class NetClient with its register-method:

```
public int register (String username, String password, String registrationToken) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(SERVER_URI + "/user/register");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .appendQueryParameter("username", username)
            .appendQueryParameter("password", password)
            .appendQueryParameter("registrationToken", registrationToken);
    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(query);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String response = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    Integer id = new Gson().fromJson(response, Integer.class);
    return id.intValue();
}
```

So, registerUser does get called, but if i print my params username or password in the registerUser-method server-side, i can see they're null.
Anybody up to tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance, grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: As you are sending query parameters, you do not need to setDoOutput(true). Try getting rid of it and it may help.

Comment: thanks for the input :)

Comment: so, client and server simply don't fit together?

Comment: the thing is, i would like to post more complex users later, also with a picture, that's why i would like to keep the client-side using the outputstream. so, i have to change the inputparams to an inputstream?

Comment: As far as I understand, you do not need to setDoOutput to true unless you want to pass something in Request Body. The query parameters are not part of the body hence the issue. When you are sending images, you would need to write that data in Request body I believe.

Comment: Put your parms in a std query appended to the get.connection.url property , changing post to get and then see if jersey marshalls values for "user " n for "password". You need to understand what jersey side is getting from URL proper vs what jersey gets from the WIRE portion of a POST.  Imo u r confusing query v post body in jersey.

Comment: alright, thanks for the advice, at least i understand now that i was quite on the wrong way, will do some more research about jersey